# Sessions not saving data

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-mvc-5

I have real time data coming from node-red.I have created controller to get data here. after getting data into controller, I'm saving the data in session. but every time session losses it's data and new data is stored in session. (real time data comes after every 10 seconds.)

```
public void GetRealTimeValues(RealTimeValues values)
{
     if (Session["real"]==null)
     {
        List<RealTimeValues> datList = new List<RealTimeValues>();
        datList.Add(values);
        Session["real"] = datList;
     }
     else
     {
        List<RealTimeValues> datlist =(List<RealTimeValues>)Session["real"];
        datlist.Add(values);
        Session["real"] = datlist;
        datlist = Session["real"] as List<RealTimeValues>;
     }
}
```

Comment: How have you defined your session state mode in your config file?

Comment: check the session state time you have defined

Comment: Ensure session cookie is passed on to the server.